# Delaying a dynamic update to get the correct value from DB

Tags: php, jquery, sql, delay

I have this jQuery code that rates a photo and then updates it's rating in the database. The function `updateRating` should update the display with the new rating but sometimes it doesn't. What can I do to ensure that the correct rating is displayed?

```
$("#rate").click(
                function(){
                    ratePhotoById( $("#image").attr( 'id' ) );
                    updateRating( $("#image").attr( 'id' ) );

                    return false;
                }
            );
```

---

```
function ratePhotoById( imageId ){
        $.post(
            "ImageRate.php",
            { ... },
            function(data) {
                // process
                // console.log(data);
            }
        );
    }
```

P.S: Ideally this should be done doing some sort of callback pattern. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also return the deferred that $.ajax returns, which lets you decouple things a bit.

```
function ratePhotoById( imageId ){
    return $.post(
        "ImageRate.php",
        { ... },
        function(data) {
            // process
            // console.log(data);
        }
    );
}
```

Then you can use the deferred's done(cb) method. This will call the callback function with the result of the AJAX request, whether it has already returned or is going to return still.

```
$("#rate").click(function(){
    ratePhotoById( $("#image").attr( 'id' ) ).done(function() {
        // excuted after ratePhotoById() has completed successfully.
        updateRating( $("#image").attr( 'id' ) );
    });
    return false;
});
```

The Deferred object also has some other nice methods, like fail() and pipe(). Check out the documentation for Deferred for more info: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Nice tip there. I just happened to be wondering if there was a way to avoid having one function being hardcoded to call another.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Based on the update to the question...

Change the ratePhotoById to:

```
function ratePhotoById( imageId ){  
  $.post(             
    "ImageRate.php",             
    { ... },             
    function(data) {                 
        // process                 
        // console.log(data);             
        updateRating( $("#image").attr( 'id' ) );
  }); 
}
```

and remove the call to updateRating from the click event handler

**OLD:**
I guess you are using ajax to update the rating (via ratePhotoById function).

Move the call to updateRating function as a part of the Success callback in the ratePhotoById ajax call
Something like:

```
function ratePhotoById(elID){
    $.ajax({
        .
        .
        .
        .
        success: function(data){
            updateRating( $("#image").attr( 'id' ) );           
        }
    });
}
```